# use getline and while loop to split a string

Tags: c++

for example i have a string:

```
string s = "apple | orange | kiwi";
```

and i searched and there is a way:

```
stringstream stream(s);
string tok;
getline(stream, tok, '|');
```

but it only can return the first token "apple"
I wonder that is there any way so it can return an array of string?
Thank you.
Let assume that the string s may be changed. For exammple,  string s = "apple | orange | kiwi | berry";

Comment: You answered your question in the title.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As Benjamin points out, you answered this question yourself in its title.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
   // inputs
   std::string str("abc:def");
   char split_char = ':';

   // work
   std::istringstream split(str);
   std::vector<std::string> tokens;
   for (std::string each; std::getline(split, each, split_char); tokens.push_back(each));

   // now use `tokens`
}
```

Note that your tokens will still have the trailing/leading `<space>` characters. You may want to strip them off.

Comment: One of the simplest and most elegant string tokenizers for C++ I've seen.

Comment: @scai: Thanks! In hindsight it needs more `const`, and a newline here or there.

Comment: Great solution! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This way it became a little bit clearer to me, what was actually happening:

std::string each; 
while(std::getline(split, each, split_char)) {
tokens.push_back(each);
}

Comment: @gebbissimo Yes that's another way to write the loop

Answer (score 4):

Since there is space between each word and `|`, you can do this:

```
string s = "apple | orange | kiwi";
stringstream ss(s);
string toks[3];
string sep;
ss >> toks[0] >> sep >> toks[1] >> sep >> toks[2];

cout << toks[0] <<", "<< toks[1] <<", " << toks[2];
```

Output:

```
apple, orange, kiwi
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/kC8FZ

Note: it will work as long as there is atleast one space between each word and `|`. That means, it will NOT work if you've this:

```
string s = "apple|orange|kiwi";
```

---

Boost is a good if you want robust solution. And if you don't want to use boost for whatever reason, then I would suggest you to see this blog:

[Elegant ways to tokenize strings](http://thecodingpoint.blogspot.com/2011/04/elegant-ways-to-tokenize-strings.html)

It explains how you can tokenize your strings, with just one example.

Comment: but this seems to be the hard code. what will happen if the string s is changed?

Comment: Probably good to note that this works because the extraction operator skips whitespace by default. I'd prefer `boost::tokenzier` over this method.

Comment: Otherwise, if you want a generic parser and don't mind using boost libraries, I'd suggest using tokenizer. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html

Comment: @user552279: changed in what sense? As I said, as long as there is space between each word and `|`, it will work.

Comment: @user: Ideally you would use a `std::vector<std::string>` to account for that but this is not the most efficient of examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
stringstream stream(s);
std::vector<std::string> vec_res;
string tok;
while (getline(stream, tok, '|')) {
    vec_res.push_back(tok);
}
```