# C++ Program to add linus users from text files

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create users in a linux terminal from a given txt file. The format of each line is in the text file is "Josh:0001". Josh being the user name and 0001 being the password. I can create a string for each line but I can't figure out how to split the string at the ":" character.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Hello World" << endl;
//system("mkdir user1");


string anyCommand="", name, userpassword;


//code to open a file 
string users[120];
string line;
//int userCount=0;
ifstream myfile ("users.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{

for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
  //code to read a user from the input file
  getline(myfile,line);
  stringstream temp(line);




  name += temp.str(); 


  //useradd vs. userdel
  anyCommand = "useradd " + name ;

  cout << anyCommand << endl;
  system(anyCommand.c_str());

  //anyCommand = "";
  //userpassword = "sosu-2014";
  //set the command, e.g., system("echo john:sosu-2014 | chpasswd");
  anyCommand = "echo " + name + ":" + userpassword + " | chpasswd";
  cout << anyCommand << endl;
  system(anyCommand.c_str());

}}

//code to close a file
cout << "Job Done!" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Sorry I commented out some of the stuff trying different approaches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use getline and while loop to split a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757721/use-getline-and-while-loop-to-split-a-string)

Comment: Don't apologise for the mess; fix the mess.

Answer (score 0):

To split a string, use the `find_first_of` (or `find_last_of`) and `substr` functions from std::string.

Comment: I still don't understand that..I know very basic code and I the string doesn't have any spaces in it.