# How to find positions of repeated characters in a string?

Tags: c++, string

How can I find the positions of repeated characters in a string? For example, the inputted string is "11-28-1995". My goal is to assign each of those values between the "-", a variable, so I would have month = 11, day - 28, and year = 1995. This is what I have got so far, although I am not sure how to iterate after the month.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() { 
string input;

cout << "What is the date?" << endl;
cin >> input;

int pos = input.find("-");

int month = stoi(input.substr(0, pos));

cout << month << endl;
cout << day << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now start at the next position in the string and search for the next occurrence of `'-'`.

Comment: Absl::strsplit.

Comment: @PeteBecker yes. It’s well written, well maintained, and provides much for than split. I included absl by default in all my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
/******************************************************************************

                              Online C++ Compiler.
               Code, Compile, Run and Debug C++ program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

*******************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
int main() { 

    string input;
    
    cout << "What is the date?" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    
    unsigned int day = 0;
    unsigned int month = 0;
    unsigned int year = 0;
    
    stringstream ostr(input.c_str());
    char c1, c2 = 0;
    
    ostr >> day >> c1 >> month >> c2 >> year;
    
    assert((c1 == c2) && (c2 == '/'));
    
    cout << "Day: " << day << endl;
    cout << "Month: " << month << endl;
    cout << "Year: " << year << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

For a more general token extractor, you may be interested in the use of getline:

[use getline and while loop to split a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757721/use-getline-and-while-loop-to-split-a-string)

Hope it helps ;)